# Cannot upload a file and call a network server via AJAX Jquery from a ASP.NET WEB forms application

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I need to access a gateway server via its IP address. The gateway is accessed via http. I need to first upload a file and then make the call on the client.
        HTML:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadExcelImport" runat="server"  Width="412px" ToolTip="Select file to upload."/>
<asp:Button  ID="CallGateway" Text="Call Server" runat="server" />
```

JQUERY/AJAX code:

```
var form = $("#form1");  
var model = new window.FormData(form);

var file = $("#<%=FileUploadExcelImport.ClientID%>").get(0);
var files = file.files;

// Add the uploaded image content to the form data collection
//var data = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    model.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
 }
$("#<%=CallGateway.ClientID%>").click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://10.242.83.21/",
        processData: false,
        data: model,
        contentType: "multipart/form-data",
        //dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var jsonParse = $.parseJSON(result);
            alert("success");
         },
         error: function (badresult) {
             var jsonParse = $.parseJSON(badresult);
             alert("failure")
         }
     });
  )};
)};
```

Upon reviewing the NETWORK in the IE browser I don't see any file being sent in the REQUEST BODY. contenttype = "multipart/form-data". The file can be a MS WORD, JPEG, PNG, TXT file being uploaded. But the return is a JSON Object containing a message. This is from a ASP.NET Web forms application. I have looked at many sites but cannot find what is wrong with my AJAX calling method above.
I tried doing the model like this:

```
var form = $("#form1");  
var model = new window.FormData(form);
```

as it did not work changed it to `var model = new window.FormData();`. It still did not work. I am not able to see the file being passed in the Request.Body in the NETWORK of the IE Browser. We use IE 11 browser.
I have already been through these sites:
http://digipiph.com/blog/submitting-multipartform-data-using-jquery-and-ajax

http://midhundevasia.com/article/sending-multipartform-data-using-jquery-ajax-snippet-2415/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806075/File-Upload-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASP-NET-Web-API

http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/f2a2f1ee-e18a-416b-893e-883c800f83f4.aspx

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2010/Sep/07/Using-jQuery-to-POST-Form-Data-to-an-ASPNET-ASMX-AJAX-Web-Service

[Form has enctype="multipart/form-data" but Request Content-Type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663959/form-has-enctype-multipart-form-data-but-request-content-type-is-application-x)

Also I do not want to add an enctype and action to my existing form on the HTML side. As it will impact my existing page.
Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Please give me suggestions.

Comment: The important is: what is "model" and how do you compose it? add the code which creates it

Comment: model information updated above. Response should be JSON. Request is a file uploaded.